# SharePoint HTML source editor of the Multiple lines of text keeps removing custom attributes of any HTML tag

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, sharepoint-on-prem, multiple-lines-of-text, anchor-tags

I am trying to add some **anchor tags inside the Multiple lines of Text through HTML source** with the **custom attributes.**

`<a customattr="value" target="blank">Test Link</a>`

After entering when I click OK button, all custom attributes(*customattr*) going away.

Any solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

customattr will not work. Try using data-customattr

```
<a data-customattr="value" target="blank">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: It works. Great Saira. Thank you!